# What does a Timespan mean when you get decimals in the hours. e.g. 43.02:10:00 and how do I avoid it

Tags: c#, timespan, battery

So I am trying to log a timespan of the battery life remaining on my device

my method is:

```
PowerStatus powerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
if (powerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining > -1)
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Battery Life Remaining {0}",new TimeSpan(0, 0, powerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining)).ToString());
}
```

But I get strange values back from time to time like `7.01:44:22`

Looking at [TimeSpan Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558(v=vs.110).aspx)

There example shows that:

```
TimeSpan( 1000, 2000, 3000 )         =     43.02:10:00
TimeSpan( 1000, -2000, -3000 )       =     40.05:50:00
TimeSpan( 999999, 999999, 999999 )   =  42372.15:25:39
```

But what do these values mean and how can I avoid getting them as they don't make a lot of sense in the real world

Comment: The number before the decimal point is days.

Comment: Yup, what @eddie_cat said, even [Wolfram Alpha agrees that 1000 hours, 2000 minutes and 3000 seconds is 43 days 2 hours 10 minutes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000+hours+2000+minutes+3000+seconds)

Comment: Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please check the MSDN documentation next time before asking a question here. This is easily answered with a quick google search of the `TimeSpan` class.

Comment: Personally I don't think this is clear from the MSDN documentation but I guess I have an answer now. Initially I was thinking it was displaying 43.02 hours and 10 minutes which is where my confusion was coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx) explains it well. The number preceding the decimal is days and after is hours.

```
43.02:10:00
```

Translates to:

```
43 days
02 hours
10 minutes
00 seconds
```

You can verify this with code:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(1000, 2000, 3000);

Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays);  // Output: 43.0902777777778
Console.WriteLine(ts.Days);       // Output: 43

Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalHours); // Output: 1034.16666666667
Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours);      // Output: 2
```